# ServiceBusTrigger in a Multitenant application - Dependency Injection for ServiceBusReceivedMessage

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azureservicebus, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant application which uses scoped dependencies to retrieve a tenantId from an incoming httprequests to the Azure functions and instantiate various resources based on the tenant.
For example:

```
services.RegisterScoped((sp)=> 
{
  var httpContextAccessor = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>(); 
  var tenantId = httpContextAccessor.GetTenantId(); // extension method
// Instantiate some other tenant specific dependencies e.g. DBContext. 
});
```

Now, I have a ServiceBusTrigger which processes messages for all tenants. The ServiceBusReceivedMessage parameter contains an object which has a tenantId property so that each message can be processes for a particular tenant.

Is there a way to have the ServiceBusReceivedMessage instantiate a resource, say a DbContext, from within the function? This is necessary because each message may have to persist some data via  a DbContext, which needs to be instantiated with a specific connection string based on the tenantId in the message.

Some things I have considered:

1. Using Activator.CreateInstance(//pass in the tenant connection string after retrieving it manually)
2. Can ServiceBusRecievedMessage be registered within the serviceBusTrigger per message?? This seems hacky (there isn't a straightforward way to do that) but also the most preferred approach as the rest of the DI containers can be leveraged without having to instantiate objects manually as in the first option.

   ```
    [FunctionName("MyCustomTrigger")]
        public Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("MultiTenantEndpoint")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusClient client,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions,
            ILogger logger,
            ExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
   ```

   var tenantId = message.GetTenantId();
   // register tenantId as scoped for this request only somehow?
   await injectedService.Process(message);
   }

Alternate approaches or designs for this?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It's not possible to do the above as the serviceBusTrigger  isn't scoped to any sort of request so DI only works on startup.

We ended up embedding the tenantId in the serviceBusMessage and then sending an HTTP request to an endpoint on the same service when a SB message is received, that ensures that the right resources are DI'ed into the consuming service layer.